# How to edit Expression Blend selected control part?

Tags: xaml, silverlight-4.0, expression-blend, expression-blend-4

I am trying to edit a specific control part within a custom TabItem Template.  In this case, it's the TemplateBottomSelected control part.

I'm having an issue where I cannot seem to view or edit any control parts within the template editor except the default TemplateTopSelected.  Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about:

[image: Editing TmeplateBottomSelected control part]

Even though I'm selecting the "TemplateBottomSelected" grid, the only thing I can see is the template for the TemplateTopSelected item.

How the heck do I edit the other control parts within the template using the editor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because these templates are either collapsed or the opacity of them is set to 0. :)

you can use the eye toggle button to only show the one you want to modify at design time, set the visibility to visible, do your changes, and reset it to collapsed.

please let me know if you need more info.